# How to calculate frequency in cassandra

Tags: cassandra, data-modeling

I have a Cassandra table with millions of rows like below.

Partition column: owner_id and date

Cluster column:video_id,session_id

```
 owner_id | date       | video_id | session_id                           | viewer_id
---------+------------+----------+--------------------------------------+--------------------------------------
  601590 | 2018-09-24 |   606816 | 0769ce70-bfc4-11e8-b753-a3c9ebf616e5 | c19ac510-9a35-11e8-9b4f-d79b67cf2efe
  601590 | 2018-09-24 |   606816 | 0af06b70-c038-11e8-ba96-ef1af2a222e5 | 0dfdc7f0-c037-11e8-bb05-8d4b0b9097e8
  601590 | 2018-09-24 |   606816 | 0bb97020-bfdd-11e8-bf24-dff4b25dd64e | ab4a1730-bfdc-11e8-8026-ddbc4c7d64f2
  601590 | 2018-09-24 |   606816 | 0dfdc7f0-c037-11e8-bb05-8d4b0b9097e8 | 0dfdc7f0-c037-11e8-bb05-8d4b0b9097e8
  601590 | 2018-09-24 |   606816 | 155dc510-bfdb-11e8-bace-516ebe0ca984 | 778f35d0-bfda-11e8-8a1e-1f00dd90d859
  601590 | 2018-09-24 |   606816 | 25378a20-bfdb-11e8-a28b-7de4597a9df5 | 778f35d0-bfda-11e8-8a1e-1f00dd90d859
  601590 | 2018-09-24 |   606816 | 2fc21170-bfba-11e8-9929-d17143803579 | 2fc21170-bfba-11e8-9929-d17143803579
  601590 | 2018-09-24 |   606816 | 3c287eb0-bfdb-11e8-b0ef-6d0d9c68d2f9 | 778f35d0-bfda-11e8-8a1e-1f00dd90d859
  601590 | 2018-09-24 |   606816 | 4265f5c0-c038-11e8-b060-552d6bdcb552 | 0dfdc7f0-c037-11e8-bb05-8d4b0b9097e8
  601590 | 2018-09-24 |   606816 | 49aa9820-bfdb-11e8-bb57-4f24d17d68df | 778f35d0-bfda-11e8-8a1e-1f00dd90d859
```

I want to calculate repeated view frequency on the basis of `viewer_id` given `owner_id, date and video_id`

Like how many times a viewer views a video for example: viewer `778f35d0-bfda-11e8-8a1e-1f00dd90d859` viewed 4 times.

The output should be something like below

```
Number of views | frequency
----------------|-----------
        1       |     3
        3       |     1
        4       |     1
```

and next is to find frequency across without date specified.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a spark job (or some kinda batch processing) to generate a table providing that information thats kept up to date with periodic runs or you can create a UDA to generate it.

I think since your narrowing it down real well with partition key and first part of clustering you can use a UDA and generate it on the request (more expensive but more real time than spark job). That is assuming that a ((ownere_id, date), video_id) is not going to have tens of thousands of entries. If it will then better to use spark or some bulk processing mechanism.